# Why .+ arithmetic operations fails on vector of same size

Tags: matlab

```
>> p=[1;2;3]

p =

     1
     2
     3

>> p1 = [2;3;4]

p1 =

     2
     3
     4

>> p + p1

ans =

     3
     5
     7
```

But

```
>> p .+ p1
Error: "p" was previously used as a variable, conflicting with
its use here as the name of a function or command.
See "How MATLAB Recognizes Command Syntax" in the MATLAB
documentation for details.
```

Also

```
>> p .* p1

ans =

     2
     6
    12

>> p * p1
Error using  * 
Inner matrix dimensions must agree.
```

Comment: works OK for me in Octave... except of course `p*p1` which is correct: you can't do a matrix multiplication on two 3x1 vectors.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is that the operator `.+` does not exist:

```
>> help ops
  Operators and special characters.

  Arithmetic operators.
    plus       - Plus                               +    
    uplus      - Unary plus                         +    
    minus      - Minus                              -    
    uminus     - Unary minus                        -    
    mtimes     - Matrix multiply                    *    
    times      - Array multiply                    .*    
    mpower     - Matrix power                       ^    
    power      - Array power                       .^    
    ...
```

Note that for multiplications, there are two operators: `.*`, which is [element-wise multiplication](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/times.html), and `*`, which is [matrix multiplication](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mtimes.html). There is no such thing as matrix addition, so there is only one operator `+`, which is [element-wise addition](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plus.html).

When you type `p .+ p1`, the Matlab parser does not recognize a valid operator, so it probably assumes you are using the [command syntax](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/syntax.html) and tries to make the function call with string literals `p('.+', 'p1')`. Since `p` is not a function, you get the error message you see.

This 'command syntax' is convenient in that it can save you typing a few characters (i.e. `load data.mat` instead of `load('data.mat')`. The problem is that this leads to ambiguity in interpreting statements, see the page [that was linked directly](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/command-vs-function-syntax.html) by your error message. This can give surprising results, as your question shows. This is one of the shady sides of Matlab's syntax.

Answer (score 2):

The operator `".*"` performs an elementise multiplication of the two arrays.

The `"*"` operator performs a mutrix multiplication of the two arrays, which in your case cannot be done on two 3x1 vectors, hence Matlab reports an error.

The `".+"` operator does not exist in Matlab. In this case, Matlab thinks you are using the `"."` syntax to reference an element of a structure or function, hence the error you are getting.